# Yahoo Boss api error

Tags: java, search, yahoo-boss-api

I am new for OAuth and for yahoo apis. My problem detail is as follows: In my current J2EE project i need to use a web search api (i choosed Yahoo Boss api).
Till now I have done below the following things:
I have added project detail at https://developer.apps.yahoo.com/projects and got Consumer Key, Consumer Secret etc.
I am trying to run this simple java example given at: http://developer.yahoo.com/boss/geo/docs/codeexamples.html . I using Consumer Key, Consumer Secret which I got after adding my project detail. But when ever I am trying to run this example, I am getting status code = 503 which means service unavailable. 2-3 time I have got response in XML also.
Please let me know if I am doing any thing wrong here. Also how can I implement my requirement. Any pointer in tghis regard will be very helpful.

Comment: See also: [Yahoo BOSS Search (Limited Web) : Valid AppID but requires registration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068232/yahoo-boss-search-limited-web-valid-appid-but-requires-registration), maybe it'll be useful.