# Yahoo BOSS Search (Limited Web) : Valid AppID but requires registration

Tags: oauth, yahoo-boss-api

I had this BOSS API working for years, but since yesterday (I think), we don't get any new results , only this message:

> {"error":{"lang":"en-US","description":"Valid AppID but requires
>   registration."}}

Other people seem to have the same problem, since the question was posted on Yahoo BOSS board as well, but without answer, I just thought maybe someone here will know what to do :)

Credit card and billing seem to be in order.

Is there anything I can do from my side, or is this yahoo's issue?

Thanks!

Dushan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of April 11, 2018, the Yahoo BOSS API is really not working anymore (it's indicated as March 31, 2016, but it actually worked until April 2018).

https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/

Comment: Yeah, this question was from 2015, it was a different problem back then :-)

Comment: I know, but it still comes up in google search results! :)

Comment: Alright, you win, take your "accepted answer" upvote :-)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be to test your AppID in clean environment.

Either by testing [Example Code provided at BOSS Search API](https://developer.yahoo.com/boss/search/#get-started) and see if you get the same error.

Or by [querying directly boss.search table](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20boss.search%20where%20q%3D%22pizza%22%20AND%20ck%20%3D%20%22X%22%20AND%20secret%3D%22X%22%3B) at Yahoo Console (populate your `ck` and `secret`).

So maybe it's just temporary glitch. If it is not, [contact Yahoo Support](http://fe.boss.yahoo.com/support.php).

Comment: Yeah, Yahoo guys said it is a problem on their side, and that if it makes me feel better, I'm not the only one :D

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo BOSS support confirmed it was something on their own side but they were dragging their feet over a month. All it was needed was to create a new account with Yahoo, register an app and fill in the same billing info. With the new account created everything worked fine :)